# What is the meaning of writing a state in its Bloch representation?

Tags: terminology-and-notation, bloch-sphere

What is the meaning of writing a state $|\psi\rangle$ in its Bloch representation. Would I be correct in saying it's just writing out its Bloch vector?

Comment: The short answer is "yes."  Read Sanchayan's answer for a complete understanding :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes. The [Bloch sphere](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bloch_sphere) formalism is used for *geometrically* representing [pure and mixed states](https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/questions/1365/whats-the-difference-between-a-pure-and-mixed-quantum-state) of two-dimensional quantum systems a.k.a qubits. Any **pure state** $|\Psi\rangle$ of a qubit can be written in the form:

$$|\Psi\rangle = \cos\frac{\theta}{2}|0\rangle + e^{i\phi}\sin\frac{\theta}{2}|1\rangle$$ where $0\leq \theta\leq \pi$ and $0\leq \phi\leq 2\pi$. This $|\Psi\rangle$ can be represented on the Bloch sphere as:

[image: Bloch Sphere]

The Bloch vector $\vec{a}\in \Bbb R^3$ is basically $(\sin\theta \cos\phi, \sin\theta\sin\phi, \cos \theta) = (a_1,a_2,a_3)$.

To represent **mixed states** you need to consider the corresponding density operator $\rho$. the set of states of a single qubit can be described in terms of $2\times 2$ [density matrices](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Density_matrix) and as $\{I,X,Y,Z\}$ [forms a basis](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/292102) for the vector space of $2\times 2$ Hermitian matrices, you can write the density operator as $$\rho = a_0I+a_1X+a_2Y+a_3Z = \frac{1}{2}\begin{pmatrix}1+a_3 & a_1-ia_2 \\ a_1+ia_2 & 1-a_3\end{pmatrix}.$$ As density matrices always have trace $1$, and here $\mathrm{tr}(\rho)=2a_0$, so $a_0$ is necessarily $\frac{1}{2}$. So from here you can find out the Bloch coordinates of the any mixed state i.e. $(a_1,a_2,a_3)$ after performing the Pauli decompostion of the density matrix. If you're wondering what ensures that $|\vec{a}|\leq 1$, it's the [positive semidefiniteness](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/518890/prove-that-every-positive-semidefinite-matrix-has-nonnegative-eigenvalues)! The two eigenvalues of $\rho$ are $\frac{1}{2}(1+|\vec{a}|)$ and $\frac{1}{2}(1-|\vec{a}|)$. Thus, to ensure that the second eigenvalue is non-negative, $|\vec{a}|\leq 1$. The three properties of density matrices which you should drill into your brain are: **self-adjointness**, **positive-semidefiniteness** and **unit trace**; prove them as an exercise.

Once you determine the values $a_1,a_2$ and $a_3$ from the density operator, you can easily find the location of the qubit state $(\sin\theta \cos\phi, \sin\theta\sin\phi, \cos \theta)$ *inside* the Bloch sphere. Let me emphasize on this point: pure states lie on the Bloch sphere (i.e. $|\vec{a}|=1$) whereas mixed states lie inside the Bloch sphere (i.e. $|\vec{a}|<1$). If you're mathematically inclined, you'll also love to think about the Bloch sphere in terms of [stereographic projections](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stereographic_projection); it's excellently summarized in this [Physics SE answer](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/220951/199113). I'll attach the image from there, which is originally from [this blogpost](http://stla.github.io/stlapblog/posts/BlochSphere.html) (the article is in French, sorry :).

[image]

Here are a few "further readings" for you:

- [Understanding the Bloch sphere](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/204090)
- [Density matrices for pure states and mixed states](https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/questions/2347)
- [Why do Bloch sphere wavefunctions have half angles?](https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/questions/4118)
- [Purity of mixed states as a function of radial distance from origin of Bloch ball](https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/questions/5603)
- [Alternative to Bloch sphere to represent a single qubit](https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/a/1633)
- [Can the Bloch sphere be generalized to two qubits?](https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/questions/4699)
- [Why is an entangled qubit shown at the origin of a Bloch sphere?](https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/q/5147)

Essentially, go through the [bloch-sphere](/questions/tagged/bloch-sphere) tag; you'll find several interesting questions and answers, which should clarify most of your beginner confusions about the Bloch sphere formalism.